# check for page error

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Is there any method or method to check if page loaded with Watir returned error - such as server unavailable ?

I want to see if the page was loaded correctly or if browser returned any error.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature (getting the http status code) of either watir or webdriver.  The general philosophy has been that the tools automate as a user does, and the user cannot see the http status.  (although they will see a resulting error page)  Also since the browser is the one making the call, not some underlying code, it has the status code but that is not really exposed to the user nor is it info that is easily available via the DOM etc.  Here's [a webdriver issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141) that's been getting this kind of request for around 3 years and as you can see the the devs are pretty adamant that this is not something they want to add to webdriver

Generally a good test for if you got the right page is to check the page title to see if it is what is expected.  if it's not then you could screenshot or otherwise examine the page you did get to try and make some sense out of it (may well be a standard error page from the webserver)

If you really want to be able to look at the HTTP status code itself, There are ways such as using a proxy or making a second call to the URL (which you would have to save in advance, which might not always be easy) using a http level call from your code using something like httparty.)

There are a couple of ruby 'proxy' gems, including one created very recently.  but I have not used them and could not tell you how to set them up so that http calls from the browser would go through the proxy and be available for you to inspect that way.  You'd probably need to talk to the authors of one of the proxies and ask if that sort of thing would be possible or not.  (I know I've seen people talking about doing a similar thing in Java with webdriver, so it should also be possible with ruby)